# UX Affordance for Distinguishing User-Created from System-Generated Content

Tags: user-expectation, user-generated-content

Our system has a collection of objects (school classes, to be specific) that are currently all system-generated through an integration with an external database. The classes are displayed as a grid of tiles on a page.

We're adding the functionality to allow teachers to create their own school classes that will mostly be functionally identical to the ones created by the system, but with a couple of exceptions, and we'd like to distinguish easily between user-created and system-generated classes visually.

Is there an affordance or design pattern that would read well as "user-created" for this purpose?

Comment: In what way will it help the user to know that a class is user-created vs. system created? Is it important for them to know this to accomplish a task, or more of an FYI?

Comment: @Izquierdo, there are certain actions they can't perform on a user-created class, and certain actions they can only perform on a user-created class.  Not many, but a few.

Comment: Colour code them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to UX StackExchange!

I think here the problem is knowing the author of the classroom, so in that case simply articulate them:

[image: an image containing three classes in a single row, bearing "class name" and "class author" as descriptors]

This is simply "text", or "label". (To answer your question about affordances.)

Now, you want to distinguish between "user-created" and "system-created"; in this sense, I think it'd be more user-friendly if the system-created ones were to be marked by the School itself, designating the "school" as the "system":

[image: depiction of three classes in a row, intro to UX by John Doe, design thinking by black sea design school, and ui design fundamentals by susan b. doe]

Here it's fairly clear about which is which, without mentioning "user-created" or "system-created" at all.

### Update:

It seems that this system is designed for the teachers, not the students. The above answer was designed for a students' dashboard. Here's my idea for a teachers' dashboard. See comments for discussion.

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution, with a bit of a clarification needed: most often, a teacher's dashboard includes classes created by the system and classes created by that teacher.  There won't be many classes created by other teachers, if any.  So to be more clear: for the teacher, they will be seeing "classes I created" and "classes that were handed to me."  I am concerned that adding their full name would add information that is generally unhelpful.

Comment: @ilinamorato Forgive me, I thought this was the students' dashboard. In that case, then, I would suggest changing the names to these designations: "Created by you" (for the user-created classes) or "Assigned to you" (for the system-designed classes). Another solution would be to distinguish it with headings. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I hadn't even considered headings.  Thank you, that's very helpful!